# client side validation not working asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create client side validation. When I keep the fields on page empty and click submit button, the server side validation is working but client side validation is not working. I am also including `jqueryval` bundle in layout.cshtml file.

```cs
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

I have also check following line in web.config file

```cs
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

Model:

```cs
public class File
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FileSrc { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>File</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileSrc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" id="FU" multiple />
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FileSrc,new { id="fm"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileSrc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

AM I missing anything?

Comment: Show some of your model and view (and have you also included `jquery-{version}.js`)

Comment: yes `jquery-{version}`.js included

Comment: @StephenMuecke _Layout.cshtml or actual view?

Comment: The view (just 1 or 2 properties of the model including its validation attributes  and how you generating the view for them)

Comment: The view and the model look fine (except the `[Required]` on `DateCreated` is not really required - a `DataTime` cannot be `null`, and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FileSrc` wont work because the associated input is hidden). Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: yes datecreated was mistakenly marked `Required` I fixed it.model.FileSrc and filled via js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120346/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-alex).

Comment: no error on console

Answer (score -2):

attach jquery unobtrusive script too